# Preview csv file in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, csv

I have a problem in outlook 2016. Don't work preview files csv in outlook, but files excel(xlsx) works without problem. Outlook shows message: This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it.
Could we help me?

Comment: Are CSV files associated with Excel?

Comment: Of course.  [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6EAm4BoO_yzV0Eyam5VbzZnV28)

Comment: You need an Outlook preview handler for CSV files. Preview handlers are associated with file types, not the programs that open them.

Comment: Everything works. I downloaded program PreviewConfig for Windows 7 and changed preview type .csv on the Plaint-text. Thanks for the help

Comment: However, this just previews csvs as a garble of text, it doesn't use Excel to preview them like a .xlsx file, making it only vaguely useful. Anyone have a solution that uses Excel to preview the csv?

Comment: Anyone know if this works for Windows 10?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like, for some reason, Microsoft doesn't think that .csv files are Excel files.  I'm using Outlook 2016 and Excel from Office 365, but I think this may work with other versions.

In the registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, there are entries for each file extension.  Under .xls and other "true" Excel file types, there is a key ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} with the Default key value {00020827-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.  The ShellEx key is missing from the .csv entry.

I added the ShellEx and {8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} with the value above, and lo!  I can preview .csv files in Excel.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  +-.csv
      +-ShellEx
          +-{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}
              +-(Default), REG_SZ, {00020827-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

Comment: Anyone know if this works for Windows 10?

Comment: That was where I set this up - yes, it works for Windows 10.